# Método no compatible IE11

Tags: javascript

Tengo el sigueinte código que con la versión de IE11 no me funciona.

```
var obj = Object.keys(obj).sort().reduce((a, v) => {a[v] = obj[v];return a; }, {});
```

¿Existe alguna forma abreviada o alternativa que pueda hacer esto?

Comment: Hola, creo que se puede pensar una forma alternativa, lo único que hace el código es ordenar los atributos del objeto, ¿no es así?

Comment: A veces aquí https://babeljs.io/repl te da una idea de como solucionarlo

Answer (score 3):

Las funciones flecha no son aceptadas por IE, son una novedad de ES2015, mientras que IE11 (última versión) es anterior.

Sustituye `(a, v) => {a[v] = obj[v];return a; }` por `function(a, v) {a[v] = obj[v];return a; }` y funcionará.

Por otro lado, lo único que hace ese código es copiar un objeto

Answer (score 1):

Para agregar a la [respuesta de Pablo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/298429/77052), existe un *"compilador"* donde podrás traducir tu código de ES2015 a ES5 llamado [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=G4QwTgBA9gRgVhAvBA8vApgYwC4DoDW6AngM4AUscAlLiVGNmTWOgCYCum6ZZIANBGBUkAPggBvEAG1gAXSTR4M2QG4W2dmAB2EECogBfAeINUVAKCA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.6.2&externalPlugins=)

Por ejemplo, tu entrada sería:

```
var obj = Object.keys(obj).sort().reduce((a, v) => {a[v] = obj[v];return a; }, {});
```

y esto, generaría el código

```
var obj = Object.keys(obj).sort().reduce(function (a, v) {
  a[v] = obj[v];
  return a;
}, {});
```

Que será compatible con IE11